# What is the area for the shaded region? The region is enclosed by a circle, a quarter circle and an angle. The measurements are given in descriptions.

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, area

What is the area for the shaded region `HIML`. Each side of the square is $100$, taking $\pi = 3.142$.

Quarter circle `ALMC` center at D, `r = 100`.

Circle `HKJI`, `r = 50`.

H, I , J, K are the mid-points of AB, BC, CD and DA respectively.

I know how to find the area for a sector or arc, but can't figure out to solve this one. A solution/suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynphr.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. You should also post your working: what steps have you taken to solve the problem and where did you get stuck?

Comment: HIML is the difference of DHID minus a circular sector. Can you express DHBI as a difference of areas that can be calculated?

Comment: Look like area is: $625 \left(4+\pi -8 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)$.I solved with Mathematica using `ImplicitRegion` and `Area` functions.

Comment: @John Omielan, I've added some information which I thought not required because some information are clearly visible (implied) even those are not said in words.

Comment: @shortmanikos, I do not know how find DHBI, but I can find the HBI area. If I add H & I, then I can find the triangle area of DHI and HBI which combined can give us DHBI, but you talking about difference of regions, which are they? Please.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk, I have some experience with mathematica but here I want to go for either geometrical or calculas.

Comment: @Kenta S, I’ve added new information, could you please consider to open this question for accepting answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume unit square for simplicity. Note that the shaded area is enclosed between the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-\frac12)^2 + (y-\frac12)^2 =\frac14$. In polar coordinates, they become $r=1$ and $r=\frac12( \sin \theta +\cos\theta+\sqrt{\sin2\theta})$. Then, the area is within the angles
$(\tan^{-1}\frac12, \frac\pi2- \tan^{-1}\frac12)$ and can be integrated as

\begin{align}
&\int_{\tan^{-1}\frac12}^{\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\frac12}
\frac12 \left[ r^2_1(\theta) - r^2_2(\theta)  \right]d\theta \\
=&\frac12\int_{\tan^{-1}\frac12}^{\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\frac12}
\left[\frac14 (\sin \theta +\cos\theta+\sqrt{\sin2\theta})^2-1\right] d\theta \\= &\frac14-\frac{3\pi}{16}+ \tan^{-1}\frac12
\end{align}

Edit: Geometric solution

Let [.] denote areas. Then, the shaded area is

$$A= [DHBI] - [HBI] - [DLM]\tag1$$

where $[DHBI] = \frac12$, $ [HBI]= \frac14 ( 1- \pi(\frac12)^2)= \frac14- \frac\pi{16}$, and
$$ [DLM] = \frac 12\angle LDM \cdot 1^2 = \frac12(\frac\pi2-2\angle CDI )= \frac\pi4- \tan^{-1} \frac12$$

Plug the three individual results into (1) to arrive at

$$A= \frac14-\frac{3\pi}{16}+ \tan^{-1}\frac12$$

Comment: It actually gives 0.12 (approx.) I get the exact same answer with simple geometry. It is correct. $tan^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $tan$, namely $arctan$, NOT $tan$ raised to the power of -1.

Comment: You’re right, I calculated wrongly, it gives me 0.12299.

Comment: I don’t understand why they closed a well defined question, it shouldn’t be closed.

Comment: @Quanto, Could you please post your geometry solution here.

Comment: @abhimanyue - I’ll take a shot and amend the answer

Comment: @abhimanyue - please see the edit for the geometric solution

Comment: @Quanto, Last question, for a square of size 100x100, the answer will be 10,000 times of this answer, [since we are calculating area. Just to make sure].

Comment: @abhimanyue - correct